# Using NVidia FxAA in my code: Whats the licensing model?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, 3d, directx

Came across this implementation of FxAA from NVidia.

> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/sdk/11/FXAA_WhitePaper.pdf
>       http://timothylottes.blogspot.in/2011/12/fxaa-40-stills-and-features.html

The source code as such does not have a license header neither could I find any information about the licensing. Is it fine to integrate this to the software having a commercial license?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is public domain apparently:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, updates/derivatives of FXAA 3.11 are now also licensed under [NVIDIA's GameWorks OpenGL Examples](https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworks-vulkan-and-opengl-samples):

- [FXAA 3.11](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/GraphicsSamples/blob/80e8ba8f5e8935821513207033490735dd3279d8/samples/es3-kepler/FXAA/FXAA3_11.h)
- [License](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/GraphicsSamples/blob/master/license.txt), the gist of which is summarised by this excerpt:

  > License:  Subject to the terms of this Agreement, NVIDIA hereby grants
  >   to Developer a royalty-free, non-exclusive license to possess and to
  >   use the Materials.  The following terms apply to the specified type of
  >   Material:
  >
  > Source Code:  Developer shall have the right to modify and create
  >   derivative works with the Source Code.  Developer shall own any
  >   derivative works ("Derivatives") it creates to the Source Code,
  >   provided that Developer uses the Materials in accordance with the
  >   terms of this Agreement.  Developer may distribute the Derivatives,
  >   provided that all NVIDIA copyright notices and trademarks are used
  >   properly and the Derivatives include the following statement: "This
  >   software contains source code provided by NVIDIA Corporation."

This means it requires attribution, but is still significantly more permissive than many other software licences with respect to commercial software use.

With respect to finding original disclosure of how the code would be licensed, I've had a bit of a trawl via [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/)  and the (possibly suspect) [Archive.is](http://archive.is/). There doesn't seem to have been any mention of licensing intent, even though blog posts by other people indicate it's public domain:

- Original posting via [Archive.is](http://archive.is/Y7Ns)
- Subsequent updates: [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20110831051424/http://timothylottes.blogspot.com/)

It looks like sigman's answer is about as good as it's going to get in terms of backing for use as public domain code (outside of the NVIDIA licence linked above). Or outside of reaching out to Timothy Lottes himself (again). ;)

Comment: The link to the GameWorks related pages seems to be broken